# MEF и составные плагины

Tags: c#, плагин

Хочется местами прикрутить плагины, чтобы явно выделить прикладную логику от системной.

Посмотрел на два основных варианта из коробки - MAF и MEF. Второй выглядит намного проще и интуитивнее, не сообразил только, как сделать плагины составными.

Пишу парсер сайтов, соответственно - по плагину на сайт или даже на пару сайтов сразу. Возникает вопрос - можно ли скомпоновать требования как то?

Т.е. при загрузке реализации условного `ISite` требуется найти соответствующую реализацию `ILogin` и `INHibernateMapping`. Один класс, как это описано в простых примерах, меня не устраивает, у меня их минимум три на валидную сущность. Можно описать в MEF такие зависимости вообще или мне придётся создавать какой то общий интерфейс `IPlugin`, в котором будут находиться все связанные интерфейсы и использовать дальше импорт\экспорт только для общего интерфейса `IPlugin`?

UPD: основной кейс - когда все необходимые интерфейсы всё таки реализуются в одной сборке. По возможности - в разных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил объединить все зависимости в один интерфейс, чтобы было проще работать с этим. Условно как то так он выглядит:

```
  public interface IPlugin
  {
    string Name { get; }
    System.Reflection.Assembly Assembly { get; }
    System.Type LoginType { get; }
    Services.Setting GetSettings();
  }
```

Реализации в плагинах достаточно пометить аттрибутом:

```
  using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
  [Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
```

Ну и главное, ради чего возился, загрузка с валидацией:

```
private static IEnumerable<IPlugin> GetPluginsFrom(string path)
{
  if (Directory.Exists(path))
  {
    try
    {
      var result = new List<IPlugin>();
      var container = new CompositionContainer(new DirectoryCatalog(path));
      var ione = typeof (IOne);
      var itwo = typeof (ITwo);
      foreach (var plugin in container.GetExportedValues<IPlugin>())
      {
        try
        {
          if (!ione.IsAssignableFrom(plugin.OneType))
            throw new Exception($"Type in property {nameof(plugin.OneType)} of " +
                                           $"type {plugin.GetType()} must be implement {ione} interface.");

          if (!itwo.IsAssignableFrom(plugin.LoginType))
            throw new Exception($"Type in property {nameof(plugin.LoginType)} of " +
                                           $"type {plugin.GetType()} must be implement {itwo} interface.");
          result.Add(plugin);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          Log.Exception(e);
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Log.Exception(ex, string.Format("Plugins from {0} cannot be loaded.", path));
    }
  }
  return Enumerable.Empty<IPlugin>();
}
```

Comment: Хоть комментарий бы, что не так. Я пока в процессе написания ещё, сам не уверен, что это удобно вообще.